# MySQL Relational query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need a query suggestion.

I have 3 tables with table schema as below:

```
clause_type:
-------------
clause_type_id  clause_type_title
--------------  ------------
1               clause type 1
2               clause type 2


clause:
-------
clause_id   clause_type_id      clause_title        position_no
---------   ------------        ------------        -----------
1           1                   clause 1            1
2           1                   clause 2            2
3           2                   clause 3            1


clause_type_link_clause:
-----------------------
clause_id   clause_type_id      position_no
---------   ------------        ------------
3           1                   3
```

In "clause" table column "clause_id" is auto increment column. A clause can have 1:N clause_types. So I have 3rd table "clause_type_link_clause" to maintain this 1:n relationship. As you can see, along with "clause 1 & 2", "clause 3" is also linked to "clause type 1". I need to form query in such a way that all the "causes" belongs to particular "clause_type" should be returned:

```
Expected result:

clause_id   clause_type_id      clause_title        position_no
---------   ------------        ------------        -----------
1           1                   clause 1            1
2           1                   clause 2            2
3           1                   clause 3            3
3           2                   clause 3            1
```

I tried with some sort of JOINS, but couldn't succeeded.

```
SELECT 
  clause_type.`clause_type_id`,
  clause.`clause_id` 
FROM
  `clause` AS clause,
  `clause_type` AS clause_type 
  LEFT JOIN `clause_type_link_clause` AS clause_type_link_clause 
    ON (
      clause_type_link_clause.`clause_type_id` = clause_type.`clause_type_id`
    ) 
WHERE clause_type.`clause_type_id` = clause.`clause_type_id`
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would remove `caluse_type_id`, and `position_no` from your `clause` table, and store these soley in `clause_type_link_clause`, this will avoid storing similar information in two different places.

To do this tranformation you could use:

```
INSERT INTO clause_type_link_clause (Clause_ID, Clause_Type_ID, Position_No)
SELECT  Clause_ID, Clause_Type_ID, Position_No
FROM    Clause
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    clause_type_link_clause
            WHERE   clause_type_link_clause.Clause_ID = Clause.Clause_ID
            AND     clause_type_link_clause.Clause_Type_ID = Clause.Clause_Type_ID
            AND     clause_type_link_clause.Position_No = Clause.Position_No
        );

ALTER TABLE Clause DROP COLUMN Clause_Type_ID;
ALTER TABLE Clause DROP COLUMN Position_No;
```

This will make your schema as follows:

```
clause:
-------
clause_id   clause_title 
---------   ------------ 
1           clause 1     
2           clause 2      
3           clause 3     


clause_type_link_clause:
-----------------------
clause_id   clause_type_id      position_no
---------   ------------        ------------
1           1                   3
2           1                   2
3           2                   1
3           1                   3
```

So to get your desired output your query simply becomes

```
SELECT  Clause.Clause_ID,
        clause_type_link_clause.Clause_Type_ID,
        Clause.Clause_Title,
        clause_type_link_clause.Position_No,
        Clause_Type.clause_type_title
FROM    Clause
        INNER JOIN clause_type_link_clause
            ON clause_type_link_clause.Clause_ID = Clause.Clause_ID
        INNER JOIN Clause_Type
            ON Clause_Type.Clause_Type_ID = clause_type_link_clause.Clause_Type_ID
ORDER BY Clause.Clause_ID, clause_type_link_clause.Clause_Type_ID;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6d17/4)**

You can still achieve this with no schema changes as follows though:

```
SELECT  Clause.Clause_ID,
        ctlc.Clause_Type_ID,
        Clause.Clause_Title,
        ctlc.Position_No,
        Clause_Type.clause_type_title
FROM    Clause
        INNER JOIN 
        (   SELECT  Clause_ID, Clause_Type_ID, Position_No
            FROM    clause_type_link_clause
            UNION
            SELECT  Clause_ID, Clause_Type_ID, Position_No
            FROM    Clause
        ) ctlc
            ON ctlc.Clause_ID = Clause.Clause_ID
        INNER JOIN Clause_Type
            ON Clause_Type.Clause_Type_ID = ctlc.Clause_Type_ID
ORDER BY Clause.Clause_ID, ctlc.Clause_Type_ID;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9e5d/2)**

Comment: Thanks GarethD. Your solution to separate columns would work.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that you don't need the clause_type_link_clause table to maintain a 1:n relationship between clauses and clause_types. Your clause table is quite sufficient for this purpose. Since you have two tables, though, you will probably need a UNION statement:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT clause_id
    FROM clause
    WHERE clause_type_id = given_clause_type_id
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT DISTINCT clause_id
    FROM clause_type_line_clause
    WHERE clause_type_id = given_clause_type_id
```

or similar.

Comment: Yes I know, But as I mentioned In "clause" table column "clause_id" is auto increment column. I can not have two clause_id same in clause table.

Comment: @AsifMulla, Ah! I see your difficulty. Hope the suggestion is some use.